# App terminate how to run a service in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

If it possible to run a service after app was terminated. Please, help me verify following code:

```
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
  __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
       [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
       bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
   }];
```

Comment: No. If the user terminated your app it is terminated

Comment: exactly. dead is dead - end of line.

Answer (score 2):

Your app will generally never see willTerminate, because the system generally only terminates your app once it's already suspended (in the background). Once your app is suspended, it gets no further chance to act(*), so there's no callback for that.

The didEnterBackground delegate message or notification should be considered your last chance to clean things up or save state before possible termination.

(*) Okay, your app can do stuff if it's in one of the supported background execution modes, like audio, VoIP, or navigation, but in that case it either hasn't been suspended yet or it's been un-suspended with an entry point specific to that background mode.